# Angular html5 mode not redirecting

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, angularjs

I am using AngularJs with Ruby on Rails.

I set the html5 option to true in angular: `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`

But now when I try to navigate through pages in my application, it will only change the URL in my browsers URL bar. But the page it self will nto change unless I reload the page. Only then will it go to the page specified.

This is how my Angular routing looks like:

```
@test.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) ->
    # Route for '/'
    $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: '../../views/visitors/index.html.erb', controller: 'VisitorsCtrl' } )
    $routeProvider.when('/users', { templateUrl: '../../views/users/index.html.erb', controller: 'UsersCtrl' } )
    # Default
    $routeProvider.otherwise( { redirectTo: "/" } )

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
])
```

On the root page I have a element: `<h2><a ng-click="viewUsers()">Users</a></h2>`

And `viewUsers()` is called here:

```
@test.controller 'VisitorsCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', ($scope, $location, $http) -> 
    $scope.viewUsers = ->
        $location.path('/users')
        console.log("Redirected")
]
```

What could be needed more to get this kind of routing to work?

New angular route:

```
Test.config ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) ->

    $routeProvider
        .when '/',
            templateUrl: '../../views/visitors/index.html.erb',
            controller: 'VisitorsCtrl'
        .when '/users',
            templateUrl: '../../views/users/index.html.erb',
            controller: 'UsersCtrl'
```

Comment: Do you have a base tag in your html. You need to to specify the base url when using html5Mode. See the section on relative links: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location.

Comment: I have this tag inside my `<head></head>`:  `<base href="/">`. So I guess that is not the problem.

Comment: Someone suggested to use `$window.location.href = '/users'` after the `$location.path('/users')`. Would that be the right thing to do?

Comment: It might work, but I have found that if $location.path isn't working, you have a problem that will resurface later.

Comment: Okay. Do you have any idea how I could approach this problem? How to debug it and find the problem that needs to be fixed? I can provide more info if it is needed.

Comment: What you posted looks like it should work to me, so I bet the problem is another part of the app. I haven't used angular with rails, only node, so I might be totally wrong here, but my first suspicion is that it might be how rails serves the partials to the front end. I would make sure that the second template is being sent along with the other assets. I would also double check your usersCtrl to make sure that isn't the issue.

Comment: Allright, will see that I can do. Thanks!

Comment: I made Rails serve a empty page on my application index. And I also have a angular route that should route '/' to my html template that I have passed to it. The problem seems to be that angular is not serving the template at all for my route. No errors are appearing in console also so I am not sure anymore what is wrong with my implementation of angular routing. (Added my new routing in the anwer)

Comment: @Kaspar. Hello. I had the same problem with angular, html5 mode and node server. For now the best answer I got is to use `target="_self"` in the links to other pages, so it will get automatically reload. But this is a hack and I will continue research. See also here : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942028/angular-html5-mode-breaks-links-on-node-server` here `https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/AdOpBQaZY4c`

Answer (score -1):

try to use following instead:

```
$window.location.href = '/users'
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.