# angular html5 mode breaks links on node server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, html, url

I wanted to play with angular's `location`, so I created a simple app on node server.

The plan was two pages, each have buttons to add things to the url. There are index and users, here are their node server routes in `app.js`

```
app.get('/', routes.list);
app.get('/users', users.showusers);
```

Here is the index page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sp">
<head>
<script>
var sp = angular.module('sp', ['ngRoute']);

sp.config(function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});


var finalqs ;

//just print the values to divs
sp.controller("MyController", function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.url = $location.absUrl();
    $scope.protocol = $location.protocol();
    $scope.host = $location.host();
    $scope.port = $location.port();
    $scope.url = $location.url();
    $scope.c = $location.search().c;
    $scope.d= $location.search().d;
    $scope.e= $location.search().e;
    $scope.f= $location.search().f; 
    finalqs = $location.url();
});

//what prefix should it use?
function addtothequerystring(addthis){
    if (finalqs.indexOf("?")===-1){
        finalqs+="?"+addthis;
    }
    else{finalqs+="&"+addthis;}         
}

function aa(){
    //if its already up there, dont add it again
    if (finalqs.indexOf("c")===-1){
        addtothequerystring("c=1&d=2");
        history.pushState( "aa", "aa", finalqs);
    }
}

function bb(){
    if (finalqs.indexOf("f")===-1){
        addtothequerystring("e=1&f=2");
        history.pushState("bb", "bb", finalqs);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
  document.getElementById("showThis").innerHTML=event.state;
});

</script> 
<base href="/">
</head>

<a href="/"> Home</a>
<a href="/users">users</a>

<button onClick="aa();">add things</button>
<button onClick="bb();">add extra things</button>
```

users page is just plain html like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >    
    <div id="main">
     this is where content will be injected 
    </div>
</html>
```

Everything works fine, except when I click the links to get to another page. The url in the adress bar changes, but I am stack in the same page. I have to click twice to actually go to another page. Now, if I remove the

```
sp.config(function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

part, this problem  goes away. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Thanks

UPDATE
charlietfl is right, the `ngRoute` and the

```
sp.config(function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

part are not necessary for the code to work. If I remove them, I can go from one page to the other , but I canot anymore get the values from the url, `$location .search.name of any value` is empty

Comment: looks like you need to study some tutorials on how angular routing works and read the docs for html5Mode

Comment: @charlietfl I've red a lot of tutorials and a book for angular begginers and now I am asking because I am confused.

Comment: But your code is so unorthodox and you are probably fighting with router by accessing popstate. This is not how to set up conventional routes using `ngRoute`. Also should never need `onClick` in angular. Suggest you use angular as it is documented. There are numerous seed projects you can play with to get a better feel for it

Comment: @charlietfl User can hit buttons and url gets updated, so when the url is pasted on an empty window I grab the key/value pairs of the querystring and manipulate content accordingly. I am not adding routes on the url I am adding key/value pairs. The `app.get` routes I mention in the OP are in node server, not angular. I dont get  the "fighting with router by accessing popstate". You have to be more analytic. What do you suggest?

Comment: Point is what you are doing is very hard to follow , goes against the way angular is normal used and it seems you don't really have fundamental understanding of how single page app works with internal routing. I could be wrong and this is just a crazy science experiment but it is still very hard to follow

Comment: @charlietfl But this is not an SPA. This is an app with two different pages that uses angular `location` to manipulate url data.

Comment: Then why are you including `ngRoute` and setting `html5Mode`? That is used for SPA and adds to the confusion here

Comment: @charlietfl If I remove the `html5 mode` and `$locationProvider` config it works. You are right about that. But, the `$location` is depented to `ngRoute`, if I got this correctly. If I remove `ngRoute`, `$location` does not work and I cannot add key/values to the url.

Comment: `$location` is part of angular core. But you are trying to use it to read SPA routing routes and should be using `$window.location` which is the `window.location` object.   `$location.search` is not the same as `window.location.search`. Why aren't you just using SPA in the first place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86702/discussion-between-slevin-and-charlietfl).